# Where should we put the integration tests, smoke tests (not unit tests) in the intelliJ Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

We have created the SDK with Gradle project in the intelliJ and need to test it.

In IntelliJ, it will create two folders under src (main and test) automatically for each module.
This test folder (under src) is usually for unit tests.

```
   - SDKmodule/
    - build.gradle
    - src/main/java
    - src/test/java
 - library/
    - build.gradle
    - src/main/java
 - settings.gradle
 - build.gradle
```

Now we want to add end_to_end tests for the SDK. Where should we put the tests?

Should we create a new automationtests module for end_to_end tests? It will automatically create main and test directory too under src.

Is it the correct location if we put the end_to_end tests in the test directory of new automationtests module? And if so, how could we import the class from SDK module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a end_to_end folder in the test directory as recommended by gradle itself.
Quoting it: Optimally, the test source code for each test type should be stored in dedicated source directories

Even mvn has a new structure for integration test, like src/test/it.

Please refer:  [Organizing Gralde directory - separate_test_type_source_files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_test_type_source_files)

Comment: Thanks, Sanket. If so, I will put the end_to_end tests in the test directory of SDK module